# Cheerio get method not working as expected

Tags: javascript, cheerio

I am doing some web scraping in JS for the first time and already stuck.

I have a cheerio object that contains div tags I want to pull out. If I iterate through the cheerio using the each method, I can see they are all there

```
temp.each(function (i, e) {
    console.log($(e).text());
    console.log("...looping");
    console.log(i);
 });

              
...looping
0
“The square root of the amount of ducks I give"
...looping
1
Sweet Home, Alabama
...looping
2
FOOTER GOES HERE
...looping
3
```

I see that quote I want is under the element indexed at 1, but if I try to grab it with temp.get(1).text(), I get TypeError: temp.get(...).text is not a function.

There is something big I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

`.get` gives you the element, not the Cheerio object - elements don't have a `.text` method. Either use the proper property to extract text from an element:

```
console.log($(e).get(1).textContent)
```

Or use `.eq` instead, which will give you a Cheerio object containing only the element at that index.

```
console.log($(e).eq(1).text())
```